# Combining a Variable and Regular Expression in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, concatenation

I have the code:

```
$TEMP =~ s/\#NAME\#/$customerName/g;
```

Where I am replacing `#NAME#` with the value in `$customername` using Regex. What I want to do is append a variable onto the end of `NAME`.

So I want to do something like:

```
$TEMP =~ s/\#NAME . $appendValue\#/$customerName/g;
```

so it will essentially be:

```
$TEMP =~ s/\#NAME_1\#/$customerName/g;
```

Would this work or is there a proper way to handle this?

---

Test Cases:

- Hello #NAME#
- This is only intended for #NAME#

Comment: Two things: `#` is not a metacharacter (and therefore doesn't need to be escaped), and you probably want to use `\Q...\E` to quote any potential metacharacters contained inside your variable. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @MattJacob I'm rather inexperienced with Perl and am editing someone else's script. I have not because I kind of need to know if this is possible for the type of script I am creating. Basically it will look for different strings in different templates for emails. Based on prior criteria the appendValue will be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern interpolates variables, so no concatenation operator is needed:

```
$TEMP =~ s/#NAME$appendValue#/$customerName/g;
```

You might need to protect special characters in the variable, though, so use `\Q...\E`:

```
$TEMP =~ s/#NAME\Q$appendValue\E#/$customerName/g;
```

`#` is not special in a regex, so no backslash is needed (but it doesn't hurt).

Comment: Thank you. I inherited this script in a language I have 0 experience with and I don't have much experience with Regex either. I will try this and mark you as answered if it works. Or be back with more questions.